# DataSet does not support System.Nullable<> exception in c#

Tags: c#, dataset

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RST_DBDataContext db = new RST_DBDataContext();
            var d = (from s in db.TblSpareParts
                                        select new {  s.SPartName, s.SPartCode, s.ModelID, s.SPartLocation,  s.SPartActive, s.SPartSalePrice }).ToArray();
            CrystalReport1 c = new CrystalReport1();
            c.SetDataSource(d);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = c;

        } 
}
```

i am trying generate crystal report
there in sql table  SPartSalePrice is nullable due to that at  c.SetDataSource(d); exception come please solve it

Comment: If you want people to help you, please describe what you are trying to do, what the exception is and what you have done to solve the issue

Comment: i am trying generate crystal report

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [null coalescing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) or [conditional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) operators in your anonymous projection to map out the `null`:

**Coalescing:**

```
var d = (from s in db.TblSpareParts
  select new 
  { 
    s.SPartName,
    ...,
    SPartSalePrice = s.SPartSalePrice ?? 0.0,
    ...
  }).ToArray();
```

**Conditional** (Not really useful for nulls, but useful for projecting other values)

```
  SPartSalePrice = s.SPartSalePrice == null ? 0.0 : s.SPartSalePrice,
```

The field needs to be given a name (I've kept the original one, `SPartSalePrice`), and the `type` of substitution (`0.0`) should match the type of the field.

Comment: SPartSalePrice is float type

Comment: Hopefully prices are modelled as Decimal or Numeric :-D

Comment: its done now but now in report SPartSalePrice field show nothing else blank

Comment: you are great man :) its solved ... God bless you... i want give you points tell me how i can give you point that make your ranking higher

Comment: @mian Click the vote up button near his answer and mark him as answer and voila +̹̱̼̗̿ͭ̀2̧͙̘̩͓̮̫̫ͦ̾ͧ̀ͤͥ͘5̛͎̘͚̆̐ ̢̲̯͚̏̍́p̠̖̉ͤ̎͗̊͡ơͩͫͮ͏̡̪̪͙̳ͅi̷̛͓̫̥̺͎̫̳̘̞ͪ̎ͧ̆̈̾̅ͪn̻̠͙̲͈̠̰̞̜ͧ̅ͩͫ͐̒̑ͪ̚͡t̎ͥ̆͑̀̀͞͏͕͔s̸̺̩̥̬̰̉͛͗͛̅

Comment: can you vote me that i can ask more questions on stackoverflow

Comment: @RizwanAhmed Please take some time to format your questions clearly, and specify your questions carefully - this way, you will avoid the downvoters. Use a service like [google translate](http://translate.google.com/) if you need to translate into English. Also, you will gain Rep by marking answers as correct - look through your previous questions to see if any of them have been answered (or, if you have found the answer by yourself, then answer them and mark it as answered this way)

Answer (score 4):

maybe One of your object values is Null. try something like that

```
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RST_DBDataContext db = new RST_DBDataContext();
        var d = (from s in db.TblSpareParts
                                    select new {  
                                                    s.SPartName?? DBNull.Value, 
                                                    s.SPartCode?? DBNull.Value, 
                                                    s.ModelID ?? DBNull.Value, 
                                                    s.SPartLocation ?? DBNull.Value,  
                                                    s.SPartActive ?? DBNull.Value, 
                                                    s.SPartSalePrice ?? DBNull.Value, 
                                                }).ToArray();
        CrystalReport1 c = new CrystalReport1();
        c.SetDataSource(d);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = c;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RST_DBDataContext db = new RST_DBDataContext();
    var d = (from s in db.TblSpareParts
             select new { s.SPartName, s.SPartCode, s.ModelID, s.SPartLocation, s.SPartActive, newPartSalePrice = s.SPartSalePrice == null ? 0 : s.SPartSalePrice }).ToArray();
    CrystalReport1 c = new CrystalReport1();
    c.SetDataSource(d);
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = c;

        } 
}
```

you should check for null in the selection with

```
s.SPartSalePrice == null ? 0 : s.SPartSalePrice
```

whetherit is null or not if it is null then it will return 0 otherwise it returns the value and assign it to the new variable

```
newPartSalePrice = s.SPartSalePrice == null ? 0 : s.SPartSalePrice
```

Answer (score 1):

iF Data Type is String then

```
SPartSalePrice =s.SPartSalePrice == null ? "" : s.SPartSalePrice;
```

which show blank if data is null else show data.

If data type is int then

```
PartSalePrice = s.SPartSalePrice == null ? 0 : s.SPartSalePrice
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in your class if you have only one attribute nullable like this : decimal? , put it in decimal. For all of your attributes which have the question mark in there declaration, delete the question mark simply and execute.