# Join two tables in crystal report Entity Framework c#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, join, crystal-reports

I have two tables Estate and EstateType. But I dont know how to write a propper LINQ query to get them as datasource for crystal report.
[image]

[image]

```
Agency_Kursovaya_v5Entities AgencyContext= new Agency_Kursovaya_v5Entities();
    public EstateReportForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AgencyContext = new Agency_Kursovaya_v5Entities();
        //var a = AgencyContext.Estate.GroupJoin()
        //AgencyContext.Estate.Join(AgencyContext.EstateType.Where())
        //ObjectSet<Estate> estates = new Estate();
        //ObjectSet<EstateType> estateTypes = new AgencyContext.EstateType;
        AgencyContext.Estate.Where(id => id.EstateID > 0).ToArray();
        AgencyContext.EstateType.Where(etId => etId.EstateID > 0).ToArray();

    }

    private void EstateReportForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void crystalReportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //var estJoin = (from est in AgencyContext.Estate join eType in AgencyContext.EstateType on est.EstateID equals eType.EstateID where est.EstateID == eType.EstateID select est).ToArray();
        //var clByEst =
        //   (from c in AgencyContext.Client
        //    join esT in AgencyContext.Estate on c.ClientID equals esT.ClientID
        //    select c.ClientName).ToArray();
        EstateDataSet estateDataSet =new EstateDataSet();
        BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        bindingSource.DataSource = estateDataSet;
        EstateCrystalReport estateCrystalReport1 = new EstateCrystalReport();
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = estateCrystalReport1;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using CrystalReports and data from multiple tables, then the join is performed within the report (See `Database Expert... -> Links` within the report designer). You would set the report DataSource like this:

```
var est = AgencyContext.Estate.Where(...).ToArray();
var etype = AgencyContext.EstateType.Where(...).ToArray();

// You might have to enter debug mode to determine the correct Table indicies
estateCrystalReport1.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(est);
estateCrystalReport1.Database.Tables[1].SetDataSource(etype);
```

You can reference the StackOverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3861892/4812586).

Comment: Now it gives me error: DataSet does not support System.Nullable<> at estateCrystalReport1.Database.Tables[1].SetDataSource(etype);

Comment: Maybe you have some nullable types in `EstateType`? It's hard for me to know without seeing the definition. Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910210/dataset-does-not-support-system-nullable-exception-in-c-sharp will help.