# Crystal reporting using VS 2015 and MVC5

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new in MVC5, i got this error when using Crystal reporting tool,

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: 'DataSet' does not support System.Nullable <>.

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace CrystalReportMVC.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        //DbContext  
        private CustomerDBEntities context = new CustomerDBEntities();
        // GET: Customer  
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var customerList = context.Customers.ToList();
            return View(customerList);
        }


        public ActionResult ExportCustomers()
        {
            List<Customer> allCustomer = new List<Customer>();
            allCustomer = context.Customers.ToList();


            ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
            rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReports"), "ReportCustomer.rpt"));

            rd.SetDataSource(allCustomer);

            Response.Buffer = false;
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();


            Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return File(stream, "application/pdf", "CustomerList.pdf");
        }

    }
}`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910210/dataset-does-not-support-system-nullable-exception-in-c-sharp". It says that if any of you column is of Nullable type then it should be handled properly to have some default value before generating the report.

Comment: i already fix it Thank you so much ..